# How to expand this dynamic column with only 1 value

Tags: kql

This `Id` column is `dynamic` type, but only holds 1 value (`f3019`...). I want to get rid of the array so it only has the field value.

When I try `mv-expand Id` it doesn't do anything

[image]

Also the current query is like:

`Id = Target.Properties[0].value`

When I try

`Id = Target.Properties[0].value[0]`

Id returns a blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic types can hold arrays and dictionaries, but also scalar types.
The fact that `Target.Properties[0].value` does not behave like an array indicates that it is not an array, but a string.
The representation of it as an array in the GUI relates to the serving lair and not the way it is actually stored.

Use `tostring(parse_json(tostring(Target.Properties[0].value))[0])`.

- Every element within a dynamic field is also of dynamic type.
  When running on a dynamic element, **parse_json()** returns the element As Is.
  If we want the element to get parsed, we first need to convert it to string, using **tostring()**.
- **parse_json()** which is used to parse the string, returns an array (which is a dynamic element).
- The first (and only) element of the array is also of a dynamic type.
- We use an additional **tostring()** to convert it to string.

**Demo**

```
print value = dynamic('["Hello"]')
| extend value[0] // Null because it's not really an array
| extend result = tostring(parse_json(tostring(value))[0])
```

| value | value_0 | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ["Hello"] |  | Hello |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA03NQQrCQAyF4b3gHUI301nVC7h35QVKkdgGGYmZkmSKAx7eQUHcPv7Ht2oShw25EBxhqYKPNPdh7E7EnLspxP3uBfR0kuWbjYcJhgHOhRmuNGMxguTBQLKDEjJXQAFUxfr3VbLC3gzP5g299Suq0eVuWfrf9hFibEZ8A/0vL3KaAAAA)

Misleading representation in Azure Monitor:

[image: Azure Monitor GUI]

Comment: I tried this but it returns null as well

Comment: Long day... Adding an explanation

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. Is it correct to say that because of the `[ ]` that the string is automatically displayed as an array?

Comment: Yes, that seems correct. This also as nothing to do with KQL. It's a pure GUI thing.